# TypeORM join maps to table.relation.id instead of table.relationId

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, typescript, typeorm

I have somehow encountered a weird error, am joining alot of tables, a subset of the code as below:

```
...

.leftJoinAndSelect('req.steps', 'step')
.leftJoinAndSelect('step.user', 'appUser')
.leftJoinAndSelect('appUser.user', 'appStaff')

...
```

and the error I get is:

```
Unknown column 'appuser.user.id' in 'on clause'
```

and the table clearly has a `userId` column, so the strange part is all the other columns are trasnlated correctly, a subset of the generated query as below:

```
LEFT JOIN `step` `step` ON `step`.`requestId`=`req`.`id`  LEFT JOIN `step_user` `appUser` ON `appUser`.`id`=`step`.`userId`  LEFT JOIN `user` `appStaff` ON `appStaff`.`id`=appUser.user.id AND (`appStaff`.`deleted` IS NULL)
```

And a subsection of the entity:

```
  @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.steps)
  user: User;
```

Basically, they are all defined the same but end up with different output, can someone explain to me what i did wrong here or if this is a known issue.

Comment: The problem is in the line : `appStaff.id=appUser.user.id` change to `appStaff.id=appUser.userId`

Comment: @ErgestBasha that is the generated query, just please go through the question again, and advise how i can make that change

Comment: I have no knowledge on javascript. I can tell that `appUser.user.id` is the only one without backticks. Check in your script what is different from other tables